# double movement in Scrabble

Tags: scrabble

Can you resolve a dispute between myself and my girlfriend? She recently won a game with what I think is a double movement (although there's no mention of this in the rule book).

She put one two letters down to make one word, which also scored linked to another letter. But she then added another letter immediately to the left of the finished word, which then extended the second word. I just don't think you can make a second movement like this in scrabble!

[image]

My sister placed down **W**, **D** and **E**, the ones that I circled in red. Is she allowed to do that? I told her it was impossible is it?

Can you resolve this for me please?

Comment: can you be more specific?  For example: TRIP was on the board going across.  She played SO going down to make SO and TRIPS, and then added an S to the front of TRIPS to make STRIPS.

Comment: Example would help.  "one two letters" is throwing me off.

Comment: Is it your sister or your girlfriend?

Answer (score 20):

[**From the official rules:**](http://scrabblemania.net/Official-Scrabble-Rules)

> All tiles played in any one turn must be placed in one row only across, or one column only down the board.

As you know, it is perfectly fine to score for multiple different words you made on your turn, but only if you made them from tiles played that turn. Since any tiles played on that turn must be in a single row or column, you cannot play two letters in one column and *start* a word, and then *finish* it by playing another letter in a different column. If I'm understanding your example properly, then you are correct in that she made an illegal move. :D

Comment: Does this mean that you could add two words, as long as all tiles you place are in the same column (possibly with space between them)?

Comment: @TimothyJones No - if you look at the link provided, you'll see the 'five ways that new words can be formed'.  A move can 'bridge' between played tiles, but it can only form one word in doing so.